# How To Order Data From Two Columns From Two Different Tables

Tags: sql-server

So I have a column in each table that has a numerical value and I need to order them.

The StepName is the only common value between the two tables

Table1 structure:

```
StepName | StepOrder
abc        10
ghi        48
jkl        62
```

Table2 Structure:

```
StepName | SubStepOrder
abc        1
abc        5
ghi        46
jkl        62
```

Desired Result:

```
StepName | Order
abc        10
abc        1
abc        5
ghi        48
ghi        46
jkl        62
jkl        62
```

I need the step numbers with the substep numbers ordered below them and once there are no more substep numbers we then go to the next step number with it's substepnumbers

If Step 5 had 6 substeps desired result set:

```
Step 1
Step 2...
...Step 5
SubStep 1...
...SubStep 6
Step 6
```

Comment: Some confirmations - 1) Duplicates are allowed in Table1 (ie- 'abc', 10), and 2) SubStepOrder can equal StepOrder?

Comment: @squillman 1.) No I messed that up, I was looking at my results when i was doing a join, I'll edit. 2.) Yes they can be the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works if you want to order just by the step order columns and not by the step name.

```
;WITH d (StepName, StepOrder, SubStepOrder) AS (
    SELECT StepName, StepOrder, NULL
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.StepName, t1.StepOrder, t2.SubStepOrder
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.StepName = t2.StepName
)
SELECT d.StepName, ISNULL(d.SubStepOrder, d.StepOrder) StepOrder
FROM d
ORDER BY d.StepOrder, d.SubStepOrder
```

**EDIT**

Working example:

```
WITH t1 (StepName, StepOrder) AS (
    SELECT 'abc', 10 UNION
    SELECT 'ghi', 48 UNION
    SELECT 'jkl', 62
), t2 (StepName, SubStepOrder) AS (
    SELECT 'abc', 1 UNION
    SELECT 'abc', 5 UNION
    SELECT 'ghi', 46 UNION
    SELECT 'jkl', 62
) , d (StepName, StepOrder, SubStepOrder) AS (
    SELECT StepName, StepOrder, NULL
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t2.StepName, t1.StepOrder, t2.SubStepOrder
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.StepName = t2.StepName
)
SELECT d.StepName, ISNULL(d.SubStepOrder, d.StepOrder) StepOrder
FROM d
ORDER BY d.StepOrder, d.SubStepOrder
```

Comment: @JosephMartin This looks more like the desired solution since you don't mention StepName in the ordering requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add an additional flag to indicate if each is a step or substep and use in an ordering criteria:

```
with t as (
    select *, 0 substep
    from t1
    union all 
    select *, 1
    from t2
)
select stepname, steporder
from t
order by stepname,substep,StepOrder
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists."

Comment: @JosephMartin This works to give your desired results.  Sounds like your real schema doesn't match the schema in your example

Comment: Is your data exactly as presented in your sample data? This is just an example but if you specify the actual column names instead of `*` it should work fine.

Comment: Yes my data is a little different, I just thought I needed to show in my example the data I was wanting to manipulate. I made the changes to my select and looks like it worked. Looking over it now

Comment: @JosephMartin You're spot on about only including what's relevant, that's the minimal part of a minimal reproducable example, you just need to apply it to your specific envorinment.

Comment: @Stu I haven't worked with temp tables before, can you explain to me what the 0 and 1 in the select statements are doing? Are they used to determine which table gets ordered first?

Comment: @JosephMartin `t` above is a CTE, not a temp table; 0 / 1 is just an additional column added to the column list in the union of the two tables, it's not needed for returning in results but is used for an additional level of ordering. Just use `select *` on the final select to visualise it.

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the clarification .